# How do you modify the SOAP header for a .NET web service proxy generated by VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is there a way to modify the header (say to insert a security / authentication element) for Service References that are generated by Visual Studio 2008? How would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paolo has posted an approach - [Handling custom SOAP headers via WCF Behaviors](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx) which looks like it will do what you want